# Error using SyncKeyMappingFlow while using Account Framework in Corda

Tags: corda

In AccountIssueFlow, I have used
subFlow(new SyncKeyMappingFlow(sessionForAccountToSendTo, Collections.singletonList(myAccount.getHost())));

and corresponding subFlow(new SyncKeyMappingFlowHandler(counterpartySession)); in AccountIssueFlowResponderFlow

Similarly, I have used in AccountAcceptFlow for updating the ledger, but it is throwing error as the keys are not getting sync.
Please help.

Comment: There are many answers about this API, did you try to check them out? Maybe you can find what you need. You are not providing details here, so it is difficult to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcorda%5D+SyncKeyMappingFlow

Comment: My keys are not getting synced after issueFlow as giving error in updateFlow

Comment: If you could put your code here or on github so that someone could take a look, it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi @user2351600 , I believe this is resolved after we had a discussion on slack. Is that correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Sneha had worked this out with the question asker on our developer slack (slack.corda.net)

Looking over the thread the issue here was actually about some nuances with how the developer was using accounts.

Make sure you are always using SyncKeyFlow before calling CollectSignaturesFlow. You want to do this so that the corda node knows where to look for the identities you want to be involved on validating the transaction.

Something like this:

```
subFlow(new SyncKeyMappingFlow(sessionForAccountToSendTo, Collections.singletonList(myAcctAnonymousParty)));
```